# Programatically create form with trigger disabled automatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

TL;DR: How to programmatically create a form with a trigger that doesn't get disabled.

```
function createdFormTrigger(e) {
  var result = {};
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
      var title = responses[i].getItem().getTitle();
      var response = responses[i].getResponse();
      result[title] = response;
  }
  var db = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl("https://firebase-livedata.com");
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  db.pushData(form.getTitle(), result)
}

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var email = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var form = FormApp.create("Form " + e.response.getId())
  form.addEditor(email)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('createdFormTrigger')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

I create a form with a trigger (`onFormSubmit`) that active on form submit. The trigger will programmatically create a new form and assign it with trigger `createdFormTrigger`. The trigger is created but always get disabled automatically (picture attached), is there a way so it doesn't get disabled automatically?

I've added library needed (Firebase), set scopes (`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms"` & `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly"`), and made sure that I run a correct form. Can anybody please help me?

[image: disabled trigger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger is disabled automatically because the form to which the trigger is attached doesn't include a bounded script project.

One possible to solution is rather than creating a form from scratch make a copy of a form that already has a bounded script project which already include the function to be called by the trigger.

Comment: Thanks for answering. By copy the form did you mean manually copy the form or programmatically using `DriveApp` API?

Comment: I've tried this and the trigger is no longer disabled. But it's still not triggering unless I give permission to the new trigger in AppScript dashboard. Is there any way to make it approved automatically?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. I suggest you to post a new question (do some research before)